# Handling confirmation modal dialog event to check or not check the checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, confirmation

I have a `checkbox` that I want to check based on user's clicking of `Angular` confirmation modal dialog. This looks like something below:

In my service.js and HTML file, I have

```js
function changeProgramStatus(program) {
   var modalOptions = {
      closeButtonText: 'No',
      actionButtonText: 'Yes',
      headerText: 'disable Program',
      bodyText: 'Are you sure?'
  };

  confirmModalService.openModal({}, modalOptions).then(function() {
    updateProgramStatus(program).then(function(){
       program.status = true;
       toaster.pop('success','Program status updated.');
    }, function(error){
       program.status = false;
       toaster.pop('error', message);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<input type="checkbox" id="programStatus" ng-click="$ctrl.changeProgramStatus(program)" />
</div>
```

Currently the issue I am facing is even if user selects No on `Confirmation Dialog`, the `checkbox` is getting checked.

Comment: This looks like angularjs code, Please confirm?

Comment: Yes, it is for sure

Comment: What are you using for opening model bootstrap or anything else/

Comment: bootstrap version